# Unable to install Anaconda3 on Windows 10 due to invalid character in Destination File

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda

Trying to install Anaconda 3 but get this error message. 
[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Blh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the & from the name, generally having special characters on system folder can bring you some issues, especially on windows.

Comment: I've tried renaming the computer, user, or changing the name of the destination folder and I still get error messages forcing me to abort. When I change the destination folder name I get Error opening file for writing: C:\Users\CraigTerra\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py

Comment: Are you using the `Just Me` option to install @Craig?

Comment: Yes, and changing that option solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: @Craig Could you mark this a the correct answer please